Sum a cell position across sheets using a relative row
I am using the following formula:
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'START:END'!D" & MATCH(A2,MASTER!B:B,0))))
The list of sheets live in between START and END
The data lives in Column D and I am trying to find the row dynamically using the match command to return the row of the person last name that lives in A2.
Using the match portion only returns 3 as the row.
I am receiving a #Ref!
So trying to add D3 across all the sheets between START and END sheets

The INDIRECT function does not work with 3D references.
Instead in new Excel you can use e.g. HSTACK function. But it is better to avoid references to entire columns. Use ranges you actually need.
=SUM(INDEX(HSTACK(START:END!D1:D1000),MATCH(A2,MASTER!B1:B1000,0)))


I want the Match function to find the row number so for example START:END!D3

Works like a charm TU MGonet
